# Hem pants less expensively

Tags: sewing, clothing

I feel that sewing is a form of craft, so here goes.

I have some jeans that I want to shorten the length of.

I would like to do so without hemming.

Comment: Make them into cutoff shorts. That's the only way to shorten them without hemming. If you want pants with a nicely finished edge, hemming is necessary. Do you mean without sewing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found **Hemming tape**. It looks like it should work:

> Hemming tape is a smart and innovative way to hem your clothing or other fabric items without having to use a needle and thread.
>
> Wash your clothing item as directed on the care label. Avoid using
>   fabric softeners in the washing machine or the dryer, as the adhesive
>   may not stick as well to the material.
>
> Turn your clothing item inside out. Remove curtains or drapes and lay
>   them flat, with the back side up.
>
> Hold the hemming tape up against the item that you need to hem. Cut
>   off a sufficient amount to fully cover the inside of the hem. For
>   large items, such as curtains, work in small sections.
>
> Iron the fabric to create a crease in the hem. Be sure to follow the
>   care directions on the label of the fabric. Some fabrics are too
>   delicate for an iron and their hems may require a seamstress or
>   tailor.
>
> Remove the backing from the hemming tape. Handle the tape carefully so
>   that it does not get wrinkled or tangled before applying it to the
>   fabric.
>
> Place the hemming tape inside the fold that forms the hem. Make sure
>   the rough edge is facing downward. The adhesive will act like a glue
>   to hold the fabric pieces together.
>
> Follow the directions on the hemming packet and set the iron at the
>   appropriate temperature. Place the iron onto the fabric and hold it
>   there for a few seconds. Continue ironing all the sections until the
>   material is bonded together.
>
> Turn the material right side out and again iron the hem area. Allow
>   the section to cool and your article of clothing or curtain is ready
>   to use.

-from https://ourpastimes.com/use-hemming-tape-6541765.html

Comment: Terse but works for me. You can approve your own answer if you feel satisfied with it.

Comment: The added text is directly plagiarized from https://ourpastimes.com/use-hemming-tape-6541765.html  Please add proper citations when using someone else's words.

Comment: It is not plagiarized. It comes from the link I posted. Please pay attention before you make accusations.

Comment: The problem with denim is that it will fray. if using this technique, you may want to spend $ on fray check. But for all that time, effort, the supplies you are purchasing and electricity from the iron, it would be cheaper to take to the tailor at the dry cleaner.

Comment: It will be quite a bit cheaper than a dry cleaner. $6 for 20 yards of fusible tape and $4 for a bottle of fray check. I can get at least 10 uses for $10. That's about $1.00 for the whole project. Labor should be about 30 minutes. Dry cleaner = $10 DIY = $1. Plus the fun or learning some new things. :-)

Comment: It's outside the quote block, and you didn't add the note "the information below..." until after being told to include citations, thus, copied without credit. There is no reason for you to be hostile about being reminded of the rules here.

Comment: As I said previously, I included the link in my post.  I came here for help and I do my best. And I help others when I can.  But like all humans, I am not perfect.

Comment: I've used a stapler in an emergency.

Comment: Good idea. @Stefan 2

Answer (score 1):

I've "cheaped out" on occasion and just folded them in and up, sticking them into place with ordinary masking tape and ironing the pants at the fold afterwards. It's amazing how many washes the tape can go through before it needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

a waterproof adhesive, an instant glue, an iron on sizer (double-sided tape, activated by heat). Use your favorite search engine. Here we are in a NON_BOT environment. I'd imagine there may be more, but those are my top 3.

I personally have a blind-hem attachment by Singer it fits all "short shank" machines from the 1890s to the 1960s. It is an inexpensive attachment for straight stitch machines.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I had an adventure with the hemming tape.

The seam that goes the entire length of the pant leg is very thick.

The heat from my iron would not reach the tape to melt it.

I tried sewing that area, but bent my needle because of the thickness.

[image]

Comment: Hemming tape best used with less bulk. Cut the jeans an inch longer than you want, fray check the edge (or zigzag stitch, blanket stitch or serge); fold over and apply. Less bulk. Looks like you didn’t cut.